# LINQ where clause contains certain value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq

I have a field, `"Code3"` in SQL with value as something like `"A,B,C"` and in my linq code, how can i select records with `"Code3"` containing `"B"`?

```
Dim dc = New SchedulerDataContext()
Dim dataset As IEnumerable(Of Events_Tran)
dataset = From ev In dc.Events_Trans
          Where ev.Code3.Split(",").ToString = "A" Select ev
```

Comment: _What_ LINQ, Linq-To-Sql? Note that `Split` returns an array and `ToString` is pointless anyway.

Comment: So do you get an exception like _"...has no supported translation to SQL"_?

Comment: Don't store multiple values in one column. Almost always when you want to use `Split` on a database record you should instead create a new table which is related to this table and stores every token separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot split these values into their own table (which you probably should do) then this will do the job for you. If check if the value occurs at the start, middle or end of the column, and if it is the only value:

```
dataset = From ev In dc.Events_Trans _
          Where ev.Code3.StartsWith("A,") _
          Or ev.Code3.Contains(",A,") _
          Or ev.Code3.EndsWith(",A") _
          Or ev.Code3 = "A" _
          Select ev
```

Comment: deleted mine as you have changed to `StartsWith` and `EndsWith`, so this answer became correct. +1